# What does SHUTDOWN_REASON_AUTOSTOP mean when upgrading to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade Windows 7 of Dell Laptitude E6430 to Win 10. But it stuck at 85% of upgrading with Configuring settings 42% for 12 hours without any hard disk activity. After shutting it down and letting it rollback to Win 7, I looked at setuperr.log, setupact.log, setup.etl. According to setuperr.log, it seems that installer had a problem with appdb.dat file. But based on setupact.log, installer continued 2-3 minutes after that, suddenly stopped with so-easy-to-understand reason SHUTDOWN_REASON_AUTOSTOP while moving document files. And I don't even understand what setup.etl says.

Following are their last entries. Any clue to resolve this problem will be appreciated.

**setuperr.log**

> 2018-04-23 19:25:39, Error                 CSI    0000001e (F) STATUS_OBJECT_PATH_NOT_FOUND #4883# from
>   Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::DirectFileSystemProvider::SysCreateFile(flags
>       = (AllowSharingViolation), handle = {provider=NULL, handle=0, name= ("null")}, da = (SYNCHRONIZE|FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES), oa =
>   @0x193a78c2a0->OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES {s:48; rd:NULL;
>   on:[83]"\??\C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Notifications\appdb.dat";
>   a:(OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE)}, iosb = @0x193a78c280, as = (null), fa = 0,
>   sa = (FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE|FILE_SHARE_DELETE), cd =
>   FILE_OPEN, co = (FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT|0x00004000), eab = NULL,
>   eal = 0, disp = Invalid)  [gle=0xd000003a]    2018-04-23 19:25:39, Error
>   CSI    0000001f@2018/4/23:23:25:39.579 (F)
>   base\wcp\sil\merged\ntu\ntsystem.cpp(3004): Error
>   STATUS_OBJECT_PATH_NOT_FOUND originated in function
>   Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::DirectFileSystemProvider::SysCreateFile
>   expression: (null)    [gle=0x80004005]    2018-04-23 19:25:39, Error
>   CSI    00000020 (F) STATUS_OBJECT_PATH_NOT_FOUND #4882# from
>   Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::CSystemIsolationLayer_IRtlSystemIsolationLayerPublicTearoff::OpenFilesystemFile(flags
>       = 0, da = (FILE_GENERIC_READ|FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES|FILE_WRITE_EA|FILE_WRITE_DATA),
>   fn =
>   [l:166{83}]"\??\C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Notifications\appdb.dat",
>   sa = (FILE_SHARE_READ), oo =
>   (FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT|FILE_NON_DIRECTORY_FILE), file = NULL,
>   disp = Invalid)   [gle=0xd000003a]

**setupact.log**

> 2018-04-23 19:27:39, Info                         GetNewLocation:
>   Request to C:\Windows.old\Users\username\Documents\profile_results_singleegg2_noMEMC\file75.html
>   inside moved folder redirected to
>   C:\Users\username\Documents\profile_results_singleegg2_noMEMC\file75.html
>   2018-04-23 19:27:39, Info                  CBS    Trusted Installer is
>   shutting down because: SHUTDOWN_REASON_AUTOSTOP

**setup.etl**

> "The description for Event ID 105 from source
>   Microsoft-Windows-Services cannot be found. Either the component that
>   raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the
>   installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on
>   the local computer."